# xcodebuild: Returned an unsuccessful exit code while building my own cocoapod

Tags: swift, cocoapods

I'm practicing building my own pod. 
I tagged my pod, added a podspec file and followed all steps, but the podspec validation still fails.

I have the following error : `[iOS] xcodebuild: Returned an unsuccessful exit code`

Here is my podspec file content after typing the command `pod spec lint` :

```
Pod::Spec.new do |spec|
    spec.name         = "RandomGenerator"
    spec.version      = "2.0.0"
    spec.summary      = "RandomGenerator cocoapod"
    spec.license      = 'MIT'
    spec.platform     = :ios, "11.0"
    spec.swift_versions = "5.0"
    spec.framework  = "Foundation"
    spec.source       = { :git => "MY GIT SOURCE", :tag => 
    spec.version }
    spec.source_files = "RandomGenerator/**/*"
end
```

And here is the result of the command `pod spec lint --verbose`

```
    RandomGenerator (2.0.0) - Analyzing on iOS 12.0 platform.
  Preparing

Analyzing dependencies

Inspecting targets to integrate
  Using `ARCHS` setting to build architectures of target `Pods-App`: (``)

Fetching external sources
-> Fetching podspec for `RandomGenerator` from `/Users/elitia/Desktop/Elitia/Hacker/swift/RandomGenerator/RandomGenerator/RandomGenerator.podspec`

Resolving dependencies of 

Comparing resolved specification to the sandbox manifest
  A RandomGenerator

Downloading dependencies

-> Installing RandomGenerator (2.0.0)
  > Copying RandomGenerator from `/Users/elitia/Library/Caches/CocoaPods/Pods/External/RandomGenerator/24fbdd7e610122190d368443f1e96b67-ef799` to
  `../../../../../../../../private/var/folders/zc/rtmmz52s03q3pl4vgb06psy00000gn/T/CocoaPods-Lint-20190703-3687-1fmtamf-RandomGenerator/Pods/RandomGenerator`
  - Running pre install hooks

Generating Pods project
  - Creating Pods project
  - Installing files into Pods project
    - Adding source files
    - Adding frameworks
    - Adding libraries
    - Adding resources
    - Linking headers
  - Installing Pod Targets
    - Installing target `RandomGenerator` iOS 12.0
      - Generating module map file at
      `../../../../../../../../private/var/folders/zc/rtmmz52s03q3pl4vgb06psy00000gn/T/CocoaPods-Lint-20190703-3687-1fmtamf-RandomGenerator/Pods/Target Support
      Files/RandomGenerator/RandomGenerator.modulemap`
      - Generating umbrella header at
      `../../../../../../../../private/var/folders/zc/rtmmz52s03q3pl4vgb06psy00000gn/T/CocoaPods-Lint-20190703-3687-1fmtamf-RandomGenerator/Pods/Target Support
      Files/RandomGenerator/RandomGenerator-umbrella.h`
      - Generating Info.plist file at
      `../../../../../../../../private/var/folders/zc/rtmmz52s03q3pl4vgb06psy00000gn/T/CocoaPods-Lint-20190703-3687-1fmtamf-RandomGenerator/Pods/Target Support
      Files/RandomGenerator/RandomGenerator-Info.plist`
      - Generating dummy source at
      `../../../../../../../../private/var/folders/zc/rtmmz52s03q3pl4vgb06psy00000gn/T/CocoaPods-Lint-20190703-3687-1fmtamf-RandomGenerator/Pods/Target Support
      Files/RandomGenerator/RandomGenerator-dummy.m`
  - Installing Aggregate Targets
    - Installing target `Pods-App` iOS 12.0
      - Generating Info.plist file at
      `../../../../../../../../private/var/folders/zc/rtmmz52s03q3pl4vgb06psy00000gn/T/CocoaPods-Lint-20190703-3687-1fmtamf-RandomGenerator/Pods/Target Support
      Files/Pods-App/Pods-App-Info.plist`
      - Generating module map file at
      `../../../../../../../../private/var/folders/zc/rtmmz52s03q3pl4vgb06psy00000gn/T/CocoaPods-Lint-20190703-3687-1fmtamf-RandomGenerator/Pods/Target Support
      Files/Pods-App/Pods-App.modulemap`
      - Generating umbrella header at
      `../../../../../../../../private/var/folders/zc/rtmmz52s03q3pl4vgb06psy00000gn/T/CocoaPods-Lint-20190703-3687-1fmtamf-RandomGenerator/Pods/Target Support
      Files/Pods-App/Pods-App-umbrella.h`
      - Generating dummy source at
      `../../../../../../../../private/var/folders/zc/rtmmz52s03q3pl4vgb06psy00000gn/T/CocoaPods-Lint-20190703-3687-1fmtamf-RandomGenerator/Pods/Target Support
      Files/Pods-App/Pods-App-dummy.m`
  - Stabilizing target UUIDs
  - Running post install hooks
  - Writing Xcode project file to
  `../../../../../../../../private/var/folders/zc/rtmmz52s03q3pl4vgb06psy00000gn/T/CocoaPods-Lint-20190703-3687-1fmtamf-RandomGenerator/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj`
  Cleaning up sandbox directory
  - Writing Lockfile in `../../../../../../../../var/folders/zc/rtmmz52s03q3pl4vgb06psy00000gn/T/CocoaPods-Lint-20190703-3687-1fmtamf-RandomGenerator/Podfile.lock`
  - Writing Manifest in `../../../../../../../../private/var/folders/zc/rtmmz52s03q3pl4vgb06psy00000gn/T/CocoaPods-Lint-20190703-3687-1fmtamf-RandomGenerator/Pods/Manifest.lock`

Integrating client project

[!] Please close any current Xcode sessions and use `App.xcworkspace` for this project from now on.

Integrating target `Pods-App` (`../../../../../../../../var/folders/zc/rtmmz52s03q3pl4vgb06psy00000gn/T/CocoaPods-Lint-20190703-3687-1fmtamf-RandomGenerator/App.xcodeproj` project)
  Adding Build Phase '[CP] Embed Pods Frameworks' to project.
  Adding Build Phase '[CP] Check Pods Manifest.lock' to project.

-> Pod installation complete! There is 1 dependency from the Podfile and 1 total pod installed.
   Building with `xcodebuild`. 
    $ /usr/bin/xcodebuild clean build -workspace /var/folders/zc/rtmmz52s03q3pl4vgb06psy00000gn/T/CocoaPods-Lint-20190703-3687-1fmtamf-RandomGenerator/App.xcworkspace -scheme App
    -configuration Release CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY=- -sdk iphonesimulator -destination id=C1A6D42E-F49B-43EF-B367-B698E97A422A
    Build settings from command line:
        CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY = -
        SDKROOT = iphonesimulator12.2

    note: Using new build system

    ** CLEAN SUCCEEDED **

    note: Using new build system
    note: Planning build
    note: Constructing build description
    Build system information
    warning: no rule to process file '/var/folders/zc/rtmmz52s03q3pl4vgb06psy00000gn/T/CocoaPods-Lint-20190703-3687-1fmtamf-RandomGenerator/Pods/RandomGenerator/RandomGenerator/RandomGenerator.xcodeproj/project.xcworkspace/contents.xcworkspacedata' of type 'text.xml' for architecture 'x86_64' (in target 'RandomGenerator')

    Build system information
    warning: no rule to process file '/var/folders/zc/rtmmz52s03q3pl4vgb06psy00000gn/T/CocoaPods-Lint-20190703-3687-1fmtamf-RandomGenerator/Pods/RandomGenerator/RandomGenerator/Podfile' of type 'text' for architecture 'x86_64' (in target 'RandomGenerator')

    Build system information
    warning: no rule to process file '/var/folders/zc/rtmmz52s03q3pl4vgb06psy00000gn/T/CocoaPods-Lint-20190703-3687-1fmtamf-RandomGenerator/Pods/RandomGenerator/RandomGenerator/RandomGenerator.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj' of type 'text.pbxproject' for architecture 'x86_64' (in target 'RandomGenerator')

    Build system information
    warning: no rule to process file '/var/folders/zc/rtmmz52s03q3pl4vgb06psy00000gn/T/CocoaPods-Lint-20190703-3687-1fmtamf-RandomGenerator/Pods/RandomGenerator/RandomGenerator/RandomGenerator.podspec' of type 'text' for architecture 'x86_64' (in target 'RandomGenerator')

    Build system information
    warning: duplicate output file '/Users/elitia/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-akwujhxkudfgkodyxpqvnonnahsn/Build/Products/Release-iphonesimulator/RandomGenerator/RandomGenerator.framework/Info.plist' on task: ProcessInfoPlistFile /Users/elitia/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-akwujhxkudfgkodyxpqvnonnahsn/Build/Products/Release-iphonesimulator/RandomGenerator/RandomGenerator.framework/Info.plist /var/folders/zc/rtmmz52s03q3pl4vgb06psy00000gn/T/CocoaPods-Lint-20190703-3687-1fmtamf-RandomGenerator/Pods/Target Support Files/RandomGenerator/RandomGenerator-Info.plist (in target 'RandomGenerator')

    Build system information
    error: Multiple commands produce '/Users/elitia/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-akwujhxkudfgkodyxpqvnonnahsn/Build/Products/Release-iphonesimulator/RandomGenerator/RandomGenerator.framework/Info.plist':
    1) Target 'RandomGenerator' (project 'Pods') has copy command from '/var/folders/zc/rtmmz52s03q3pl4vgb06psy00000gn/T/CocoaPods-Lint-20190703-3687-1fmtamf-RandomGenerator/Pods/RandomGenerator/RandomGenerator/RandomGenerator/Info.plist' to '/Users/elitia/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-akwujhxkudfgkodyxpqvnonnahsn/Build/Products/Release-iphonesimulator/RandomGenerator/RandomGenerator.framework/Info.plist'
    2) Target 'RandomGenerator' (project 'Pods') has process command with output '/Users/elitia/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-akwujhxkudfgkodyxpqvnonnahsn/Build/Products/Release-iphonesimulator/RandomGenerator/RandomGenerator.framework/Info.plist'

    ** BUILD FAILED **

   Testing with `xcodebuild`. 
 -> RandomGenerator (2.0.0)
    - WARN  | [iOS] license: Unable to find a license file
    - ERROR | [iOS] xcodebuild: Returned an unsuccessful exit code.
    - NOTE  | xcodebuild:  note: Using new build system
    - NOTE  | [iOS] xcodebuild:  note: Planning build
    - NOTE  | [iOS] xcodebuild:  note: Constructing build description
    - NOTE  | [iOS] xcodebuild:  warning: no rule to process file 'RandomGenerator/RandomGenerator/RandomGenerator.xcodeproj/project.xcworkspace/contents.xcworkspacedata' of type 'text.xml' for architecture 'x86_64' (in target 'RandomGenerator')
    - NOTE  | [iOS] xcodebuild:  warning: no rule to process file 'RandomGenerator/RandomGenerator/Podfile' of type 'text' for architecture 'x86_64' (in target 'RandomGenerator')
    - NOTE  | [iOS] xcodebuild:  warning: no rule to process file 'RandomGenerator/RandomGenerator/RandomGenerator.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj' of type 'text.pbxproject' for architecture 'x86_64' (in target 'RandomGenerator')
    - NOTE  | [iOS] xcodebuild:  warning: no rule to process file 'RandomGenerator/RandomGenerator/RandomGenerator.podspec' of type 'text' for architecture 'x86_64' (in target 'RandomGenerator')
    - NOTE  | [iOS] xcodebuild:  warning: duplicate output file '/Users/elitia/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-akwujhxkudfgkodyxpqvnonnahsn/Build/Products/Release-iphonesimulator/RandomGenerator/RandomGenerator.framework/Info.plist' on task: ProcessInfoPlistFile /Users/elitia/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-akwujhxkudfgkodyxpqvnonnahsn/Build/Products/Release-iphonesimulator/RandomGenerator/RandomGenerator.framework/Info.plist Target Support Files/RandomGenerator/RandomGenerator-Info.plist (in target 'RandomGenerator')
    - NOTE  | [iOS] xcodebuild:  error: Multiple commands produce '/Users/elitia/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-akwujhxkudfgkodyxpqvnonnahsn/Build/Products/Release-iphonesimulator/RandomGenerator/RandomGenerator.framework/Info.plist':

Analyzed 1 podspec.

[!] The spec did not pass validation, due to 1 error and 1 warning.

/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.7.1/lib/cocoapods/command/spec/lint.rb:94:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/claide-1.0.2/lib/claide/command.rb:334:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.7.1/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.7.1/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `load'
/usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Add the option `--no-clean` to get an Xcode workspace to debug.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem my own. 
For anyone facing the same issue as I did, here is what I did :

- Make a new Xcode project.
- Re-create the podspec file
- Add a .swift-version file
- Correct the spec for sources files as follow : `spec.source_files  = "POD NAME", "POD NAME/**/*.{h,m}"`

and it worked after following these steps.